# Microsoft Access - Sub Query running very slow

Tags: sql, ms-access

I am trying to pull together a rolling 12 month total for each customer at each period end.  The Periods table has a line for each customer for each required period.

The query is as follows - which works but runs extremely slowly.

```
SELECT Periods.LTM_Start, Periods.Period_End, Periods.sa_account,
 (SELECT Sum(sa_trvalue) FROM [Sales Transactions]
    WHERE ((sa_trdate<= Periods.[Period_End])
    AND (sa_trdate>= Periods.[LTM_Start]) )
    AND 
    [Sales Transactions].sa_account = Periods.[sa_account]
    AS Total

FROM Periods
GROUP BY Periods.LTM_Start, Periods.Period_End, Periods.sa_account;
```

Answer (score 1):

Your query will be slow to evaluate due to your use of a correlated subquery, whereby the query referencing the `Sales Transactions` table will be evaluated for *every record* of the `Periods` table.

You should be able to improve the performance through the appropriate use of joins, for example, something like the following should yield the same result:

```sql
SELECT 
    Periods.LTM_Start, 
    Periods.Period_End, 
    Periods.sa_account, 
    SUM
    (
        IIF
        (
            [Sales Transactions].sa_trdate >= Periods.[LTM_Start] AND 
            [Sales Transactions].sa_trdate <= Periods.[Period_End],
            [Sales Transactions].sa_trvalue,
            0
        )
    ) AS Total
FROM
    Periods LEFT JOIN [Sales Transactions] 
    ON [Sales Transactions].sa_account = Periods.[sa_account]
GROUP BY 
    Periods.LTM_Start, Periods.Period_End, Periods.sa_account;
```

Comment: Also, too, this is known as *conditional aggregation* where the former subquery `WHERE` clause is moved to `IIF` (or in other SQL dialects: the `CASE` statement).